# On Modernity, mass, and morality

Tags: political-philosophy, feminism, arendt

Arendt, in her book *The Human Condition* identified the 'rise of the social' as part of the movement of modernity; this is an expansion of the private sphere of the household (*oikos*) into the public sphere (*polis*); the public sphere where action is actually possible (by this Arendt means political action - her archetype is the Greek polis and the citizen who *acts* in the public sphere; and it is by his actions there that he is noted as a citizen).

The social  is also named by mass - mass-media, mass-education etc.

Q. Can we say that *social* media is it's latest manifestation? For virtually, we appear to live in a many-mansioned house.

Q. Supposing there is such a thing as feminine morality or ethic (not neccessarily tied to females); and tied to the *oikos* (home, household); does this help explain its rise, given the expansion of the *oikos* at the expense of the *polis*; and recalling that the word *oikos* lies at the root of the words ecology and economy.